# Python 3.3 Importing a class I wrote

Tags: python

I wrote the following class to play with stacks.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

I am trying to import it into another file using

```
import stack
```

but when I call `s = Stack()` it says it is not defined

Comment: `s = stack.Stack()` will be better.

Comment: Or if you do `from stack import Stack` then you can do `s = Stack()`, assuming that the source file containing your `Stack` class is called "stack.py", and it's in the current directory, along with the script that has `s = Stack()`.

Answer (score 7):

You imported the module `stack`. The class Stack is inside that module. You either need to do

```
import stack
s = stack.Stack()
```

or import the Stack class directly:

```
from stack import Stack
s = Stack()
```

Comment: FYI I deleted my post because yours was slightly better and they were basically identical info. :-)